# hide/show rows when checkbox is selected

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a table which shows Total, Passed and Failed cases and there's a checkbox above it saying show rows with no failures.  I can't seems to make it work without changing a lot of things (I complicated in enough) ..

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="zerofailures" ng-model="showNoFailures"><label for="zerofailures">Show Features with No Failures</label> 

                        <table>
                          <tr  ng-repeat="f in feature">

                            <td colspan="1">{{f.Total}}</td>
                            <td colspan="1">{{f.Passed}}</td>
                            <td colspan="1">{{f.Failed}}</td>                                                                               
                          </tr>

                        </table>
```

Is there a simple approach for this ?

Comment: do you want to hide the table when checkbox is checked

Comment: not the entire table, only the entries where failed=0 ;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you are looking for. You need a `conditional filter` that would filter your results when the `checkbox` is checked.

**Filter usage in html**

```
  <tr ng-repeat="f in feature |filter: (showNoFailures ? failureFilter:'')">
```

**Filter definition in the controller**

```
$scope.failureFilter = function(item) {
  return item.failed === 0;
};
```

Please check the snippet below for the working example

```js
angular.module('Demo', []).controller('SampleController', function($scope) {
  $scope.feature = [{
    total: 10,
    passed: 5,
    failed: 5
  }, {
    total: 12,
    passed: 12,
    failed: 0
  }, {
    total: 15,
    passed: 15,
    failed: 0
  }];

  $scope.failureFilter = function(item) {
    return item.failed === 0;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="Demo">
  <div ng-controller="SampleController">
    <input type="checkbox" id="zerofailures" ng-model="showNoFailures">
    <label for="zerofailures">Show Features with No Failures</label>

    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="f in feature |filter: (showNoFailures?failureFilter:'')">

        <td colspan="1">Total: {{f.total}}</td>
        <td colspan="1">Pass: {{f.passed}}</td>
        <td colspan="1">Fail: {{f.failed}}</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to following solution.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="zerofailures" ng-model="showNoFailures"><label for="zerofailures">Show Features with No Failures</label> 

                        <table>
                          <tr  ng-repeat="f in feature">

                            <td colspan="1">{{f.Total}}</td>
                            <td colspan="1">{{f.Passed}}</td>
                            <td colspan="1"  ng-show="showNoFailures && f.failed===0">{{f.Failed}}</td>                                                                               
                          </tr>

                        </table>
```

It will show/hide the row on the basis of checkbox checked/unchecked.